# Proving facts for invertible functions

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

On the book it writes:

> The following facts hold for invertible functions T and U.
>
> 1). $(TU)^{-1}$=$U^{-1}T^{-1}$
>
> 2).$(T^{-1})^{-1}=T$ and $T^{-1}$ is invertible.

Since those are presented as facts, it doesn't provide proofs, and I wonder how am I supposed to prove they are true?

Comment: They are stated as axioms... but you can nevertheless prove they are true.

Comment: You aren't asked to prove they are true. They are pretty simple proofs if you want to do them though (1 or 2 lines). Just use the definition of the inverse.

Comment: The proofs will be almost identical to the case in general groups or rings with slight flavor changes due to the fact that you are talking about functions.  Note that $(ab)(b^{-1}a^{-1})=a((bb^{-1})a^{-1})=a(ea^{-1})=aa^{-1}=e$.  The only remaining thing to note is the uniqueness of inverses.  That is, if you have an element $a$ and two possibly distinct inverses $a^{-1}$ and $a'$, such that $aa^{-1}=aa'=a^{-1}a=a'a=e$, then by left multiplication by $a^{-1}$ you find that $a^{-1}aa^{-1}=a^{-1}aa'$ and simplifying from the left instead that $a^{-1}=a'$.  It follows that $(a^{-1})^{-1}=a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $U^{-1}T^{-1}=(TU)^{-1}(TU)U^{-1}T^{-1}=(TU)^{-1}T(UU^{-1})T^{-1}=(TU)^{-1}(TT^{-1})=(TU)^{-1}$

2) $T^{-1}$ is defined as the function where $TT^{-1}=I$ and $T^{-1}T=I$. From these it is clear that T is also the inverse of $T^{-1}$, which means $(T^{-1})^{-1}=T$. Because $T^{-1}$ has an inverse, it is invertible.